# Multiple pages per item - using scraped links

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

My spide looks like this/;

```
class ScrapeMovies(scrapy.Spider):

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trekearth.com/members/page1.htm?sort_by=md'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="member-table"]//tr[position() > 1]'):

            item = loopitem()
            website = row.xpath('./td[2]//a/@href/text()').extract_first()
            item['name'] = row.xpath('./td[2]//a/text()').extract_first()

            yield item
   # This part is responsible for scraping all of the pages on a start url commented out for convinience    
#       next_page=response.xpath('//div[@class="page-nav-btm"]/ul/li[last()]/a/@href').extract_first()
#       if next_page is not None:
#            next_page=response.urljoin(next_page)
#            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

What it does as of know it scrapes the table (see the starting url). I want it to then go the link (members name column) and then extract some informations from this link (link is e.g. https://www.trekearth.com/members/monareng/) and the return this as an item.

How should i approach this?

If anything is unclear please do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

**EDIT:**
nowy my code looks as follows (however still does not work):

```
class ScrapeMovies(scrapy.Spider):
    name='final'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trekearth.com/members/page1.htm?sort_by=md'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="member-table"]//tr[position() > 1]'):

            item = FinalItem()    
            website = row.xpath('./td[2]//a/@href/text()').extract_first()
            item['name'] = row.xpath('./td[2]//a/text()').extract_first()

            request = scrapy.Request(website,
            callback=self.parse_page2)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            return request

    def parse_page2(self, response): 
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['other_url'] = response.url
        item['groups'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="groups-btm"]/ul/li/text()').extract_first()
        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [meta](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) field to put item forward to next callback

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem(main_url=response.url)
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                             callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    return request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['other_url'] = response.url
    return item
```

UPD: to process all rows use a `yield` in your loop

```
    for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="member-table"]//tr[position() > 1]'):

        item = FinalItem()    
        website = row.xpath('./td[2]//a/@href/text()').extract_first()
        item['name'] = row.xpath('./td[2]//a/text()').extract_first()

        request = scrapy.Request(website,
        callback=self.parse_page2)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request
```

Comment: Thanks! But now when do i put the last part of my code which is going from page number 1 till the end (You have a list of user names on number of pages i am scraping this table + info from the profile links)?

Comment: I see two problems, one with using website adress extracted via xpath (variable xpath), the other one is how to properly merge it together? I mean visit those links for each user and then follow from page 1 till the end?

Comment: I don't understand the task which you trying to solve. One item can contain data from multiple pages - I showed you the way to do it

Comment: Visit the page I am using. I want to scrap the table on trekearth.com/members (all of the pages, as of now you have pages from 1 to 300) then i want to visit each user profile and add information from it to my main output.

Comment: @Mrowkacala I updated the answer. Please, let's finish this question, you can accept it. because all other errors don't related to the topic. I can't just write a scraper for you. If you have another problems make new questions. You can mention me there in comments and I'll take a look.

Comment: I am not asking you to write a scraper ;)! I am just asking how to properly create one part of it.

Comment: just use `yield` :)

Comment: Sounds simple :), nevertheless i will mark this question as answered and if needed i will create a new one.